# Any unique or unified definition of measurement in physics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, measurements, measurement-problem, quantum-measurements

I have not found any unique or unified definition of measurement in physics, and it seems that there isn't one.
What is a unique or unified definition of measurement in physics?

Comment: Are you asking because we need to know which observables are measured in order to use quantum theory? Knowing why you're asking might help people decide how to answer.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly No, I just ask this question because there is no unique or unified definition of measurement from classic physics to quantum and relativity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In quantum physics, a measurement is physical quantity which may be regarded as an operator, so we may think of measurement in classic physics as  physical quantity by analogy.
I think we may give definition that measurement is physical quantity.